# Python convert excel column with currency from another column using currencycoverter or other dynamic source

Tags: python, excel, currency, converters

I have following table in my excel file called output.xlsx

[image: CLIENT LIST]

```
output_workbook = 'output.xlsx'
sheet1 = pd.read_excel(output_workbook, sheet_name="Sheet1")

a1_to_convert = sheet1['amount1']
a2_to_convert = sheet1['amount2']
a3_to_convert = sheet1['amount3']
currency = sheet1['Currency']

pd.to_numeric(a1_to_convert)
pd.to_numeric(a2_to_convert)
pd.to_numeric(a3_to_convert)

currency = ''
rate = 1
pd.to_numeric(rate)

sheet1['Exchange Rate'] = 0

wb = xl.open_workbook(output_workbook)
s1 = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
s1.cell_value(0,0)

print("No. of rows:", s1.nrows)

lg = s1.nrows - 1


for i in range (lg):

    currency = sheet1['Currency'].at[i]
    if currency == 'USD':
        rate = 1
    elif currency == "EUR":
        rate = 1.2035935
    elif currency == "CAD":
        rate = 0.79816741
    elif currency == "CHF":
        rate = 1.0924002
    elif currency == "GBP":
        rate = 1.3986061
    elif currency == "NOK":
        rate = 0.12056582
    elif currency == "DKK":
        rate = 0.16186762
    elif currency == "SEK":
        rate = 0.11905152

    sheet1['Exchange Rate'].at[i] = rate

    convert_a1_usd = a1_to_convert * rate
    sheet1['a1 USD'] = convert_a1_usd

    convert_a2_usd = a2_to_convert * rate
    sheet1['a2 USD'] = convert_a2_usd

    convert_a3_usd = a3_to_convert * rate
    sheet1['a3 USD'] = convert_a3_usd

print(sheet1)

sheet1.to_excel("output1.xlsx")
```

expected output

[image]

I need using python to convert in place the value in all lines in USD

and if possible to also help on adding a new column with the usd value at the right of the current column.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Can you share what you have done already? share the piece of code where you face the issue so that others can help.

Comment: @AmitNanaware is correct, but also provide us the wanted result

Comment: I have added the code but the conversion is done manually. I still have issue with this version to have the right conversion.

Comment: and the expected output, many thanks - any optimal or dynamic way to do it is welcome